# Does Azure Data Studio have a debug Menu or option to debug a stored procedure?

Tags: ssms, debugging, azure-data-studio

I installed SSMS 19 Preview 4 and it doesn't have a Debug Menu or Debugging option. I also learnt that SSMS V17 was the last version with that capability. Then I decided to try Azure Data Studio, but still not able to see debug option. Can someone direct me how I can debug an SP using Azure Data Studio IDE?

Comment: FWIW, theoretically it's possible to use the Visual Studio debugger nowadays, but requires a little setup. [Here is the feature being voted on](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/acd874a4-6125-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0) to be added back into SSMS. Feel free to cast your vote and maybe Microsoft will listen one day.

Comment: @J.D. Definitely would give this a try, and yeah let's hope Microsoft would listen :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not available. There are other ways to do, but they aren't very user friendly.

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2023/01/3-ways-to-debug-t-sql-code/

Short summary:

> Developers are used to their tools having built-in ways to show what line of code is running now, output the current content of variables, echo back progress messages, etc. For a while, SQL Server Management Studio also had a debugger, but it was taken out of SSMS v18 and newer versions. Even when it was around, though, I wasn’t a big fan: SQL Server would literally stop processing while it stepped through your query. This was disastrous if your query was holding out locks that stopped other peoples’ queries from moving forward – and you just know people were using it in production.
>
> - Option 1: Use PRINT statements.
> - Option 2: Use RAISERROR
> - Option 3: Use Table Variables.

However in all cases you have to edit your code.

Comment: I appreciate the insight! I was hoping Azure Data Studio would be much feature rich and able to do many things including debugging; However, I will totally follow your method going forward cause you picked up valid points! Cheers :-)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to download SSMS 17.9.1 since this version has a debug option right next to the run button. You can donwload it from the link bellow.

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2043154&clcid=0x409

Comment: Can't use SSMS v17.x on higher version of SQL server